# How to get a particular username from Active Directory using DirectorySearcher in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

As many of your answers would suggest, I am able to get the details of a particular username using a `PrincipalContext` and a `PrincipalSearcher` but I was curious to learn the exact syntax and uses of filter in `DirectorySearcher`.

Could anyone help me in the right path to learn more about it, because I have a `DirectorySearcher` filter like this but I am not getting the expected results.

This is my code

```
Dictionary<string, string> Ids = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPPath"].ToString());

DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
string guid1 = string.Empty;
dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=SomeUserName"))";

dSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("isDeleted");
dSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
dSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");

SearchResult sResultSet = dSearcher.FindOne();

if (sResultSet.Properties["objectGUID"][0].GetType() == typeof(Byte[]))
{
    Byte[] objByteArray = (Byte[])sResultSet.Properties["objectGUID"][0];
    Guid objGUID = new Guid(objByteArray);
    Ids.Add("GUID", objGUID.ToString());
}

if (sResultSet.Properties["objectSid"][0].GetType() == typeof(Byte[]))
{
    Byte[] sidInBytes = (Byte[])sResultSet.Properties["objectSid"][0]; ;
    var objSid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0);
    Ids.Add("SID", objSid.ToString());
}

return Ids;
```

What I am trying to do is get the guid of the user by passing the username, but I am not getting the result and I don't know what I've done wrong in this code.

I am getting the correct result when I use `PrincipalContext` and `PrincipalSearcher` class. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo (double quote inside your search filter)? Try this search filter: `dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(cn=SomeUserName))";` - I would also use the `objectCategory` over the `objectClass` since the `objectCategory` is indexed and thus faster for searches.

Comment: @marc_s hi, can you help me what cn means? is it a container? where can i get to learn about all the filters and its description  for DirectorySearcher.. thanks

Comment: @marc_s hi, i can see form your profile that you are really good in active directory, could you help me with some article on it, it would really help me... thanks

Comment: `cn` is the "common name" - which contains basically the full LDAP path to the user account `cn=John Lijin,ou=IT,dc=your,dc=company,dc=com` or something like that

Comment: @marc_s is there a possibilty that there would be more than on result when i search with cn in active directory? is it case sensitive?

Comment: yes, absolutely - if you search for "Smith" in any given US company, there are chances you'll find *more than ONE* person with that name!

Comment: @marc_s if i am able to get result using PrincipalSearcher then should i use DirectorySearcher? what should i prefer over the other.. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122738/discussion-between-lijin-john-and-marc-s).